# Expo Push Notification using alarm volume with a custom sound

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, expo

I am using expo to write an app in react-native.

I am able to schedule a push notification and it plays the custom sound that is loaded, but I am unable to have it play on the alarm channel (using the alarm volume control). Setting the AndroidAudioUsage for the notification channel seems to do nothing and the sound only comes through on the ringtone volume control. Example code below.

The channel I am creating:

```
    await Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync("myChannel", {
        name: "myChannel",
        importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
        audioAttributes: {
            usage: Notifications.AndroidAudioUsage.ALARM,
            contentType: Notifications.AndroidAudioContentType.SONIFICATION,
        },
    });
```

And the creation of the notification.

```
    await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
        identifier: id,
        content: {
            title: name,
            body: "This is an Alarm!",
            vibrate: [0, 250, 250, 250],
            sound: "mySound.wav",
            priority: Notifications.AndroidNotificationPriority.MAX,
        },
        trigger: {
            seconds: 10,
            channelId: "myChannel",
            repeats: true,
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add this line to AndroidManifest.xml

Starting from Android 12 (API level 31), to schedule the notification that triggers at the exact time, you need to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>` to **AndroidManifest.xml**.

Expo-Notifications documentation writes it

Comment: Show me please, where in expo docs?

Comment: Here:
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#android-1